# Update Azure Website instance size (Small, Medium, Large) with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there a way to scale an Azure WebSite **instance size** (not instance count) using PowerShell? I haven't found the way.

I know it can be done using Azure CLI or from the Portal, but I want to be able to do it with PowerShell. Is this posible?

I want to **update** an existing WebSite instance size, not create a new website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you first need to know the name of the Resource Group and Web Hosting Plan to which your website belongs, which you can get from the [new Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).  Then you can change the worker size to 0 (Small), 1 (Medium) or 2 (Large).

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager

$resourceGroup = "MyResourceGroup"
$webHostingPlan = "MyWebHostingPlan"

$whp = Get-AzureResource `
    -Name $webHostingPlan `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms" `
    -ApiVersion 2014-04-01

$newWorkerSize = 1
$whp.Properties.workerSize = $newWorkerSize
$whp.Properties.workerSizeId = $newWorkerSize

Set-AzureResource `
    -Name $webHostingPlan `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms" `
    -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 `
    -PropertyObject $whp.Properties
```

Comment: Cool! Let me check in out in a couple of hours (can't right now) and I'll mark as solved

Comment: I had an authentication error which I solved calling Add-AzureAccount first (source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/es-es/98f334b1-6b00-4916-b096-21a768852b27/list-azure-resourcegroup-from-powershell?forum=azurescripting). Thanks a lot for the answer, very helpfull