# How to script scaling a Website from Small to Large?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli

We have a set of websites that are configured as Standard/Small, and we would like to scale them to Standard/Large during some periods.
There are ways to increase the number of instances, or the plan mode (free/basic/shared/standard) but nothing on size (small/medium/large).

We looked at both azure-CLI or azure-Powershell.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891582/update-azure-website-instance-size-small-medium-large-with-powershell)? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the one. I will test and come back with result. Thx a lot!